# Awk or Sed: File Annotation

Tags: sed, awk

Hallo, my SO friend, my question is:

**Specification:** annotate the ***fields*** of FILE_2 to the corresponding position of FILE_1.

A ***field*** is marked, and hence identified, by a ***delimiter pair***.

I did this job in python before I knew awk and sed, with a couple hundred lines of code. 
Now I want to see how powerful and efficient awk and sed can be. 
Show me some masterpiece of awk or sed, please!

The delimiter pairs can be configured in FILE_3, but let's assume the first delimiter in a pair is 
'Marker (number i) start', the other one is 
'Marker (number i) done'

**Example:** 
|-----------------FILE_1------------------|
text text text
text blabla 
**Marker_1_start**
**Marker_1_done**
any text
in between blabla
**Marker_2_start**
**Marker_2_done**
text text

|-----------------FILE_2------------------|
**Marker_1_start**
11
1111
**Marker_1_done**
**Marker_2_start**
2222
22
**Marker_2_done**

Expected Output:
|-----------------FILE_Out------------------|
text text text
text blabla 
**Marker_1_start**
11
1111
**Marker_1_done**
any text
in between blabla
**Marker_2_start**
2222
22
**Marker_2_done**
text text

Comment: What do you mean by 'asterisks'? I did not type any asterisk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '
    FNR==NR && /Marker_.*_done/  {sep = ""; next}
    FNR==NR && /Marker_.*_start/ {marker = $0; next}
    FNR==NR {marker_text[marker] = marker_text[marker] sep $0; sep = "\n"; next}
    1 {print}
    /Marker_.*_start/ {print marker_text[$0]}
' file_2 file_1
```

Comment: @SiegeX, the print statements need to be in that order specifically so the marker start would output before the marker body. @Dennis, yes.

Comment: @Dennis: or the `{print}` is redundant, take your pick!

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to approach this. I'm assuming that `FILE_2` is smaller than `FILE_1` and of a reasonable size.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
FNR == NR {
    if ($0 ~ /^Marker.*start$/) {
        flag = 1
        idx = $0
        next
    }
    if ($0 ~ /^Marker.*done$/) {
        flag = 0
        nl = ""
        next
    }
    if (flag) lines[idx] = lines[idx] nl $0
    nl = "\n"
    next
}
{
    print
    if (lines[$0]) print lines[$0]
}
```

To run it:

```
./script.awk FILE_2 FILE_1
```

Comment: You should use `idx = $0` since you later use `lines[$0]`. If his Marker text contains spaces your code will break as is.  Anyway, thanks for the concatenation idea, I'll be sure to use that from now on so +1 for that

Comment: Dennis, I think you hit the nail on the head! Excellent! <br> By the way, SiegeX is right about using ide=$0.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to see how powerful and
>   efficient awk and sed can be

For this type of problem, very efficient. I'm sure my code can be further reduced.

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '
  FNR == NR {
     if ($0 ~ /Marker_1_start/){m1=1;next}
     if ($0 ~ /Marker_2_start/){m2=1;next}
     if ($0 ~ /Marker_1_done/){m1=0}
     if ($0 ~ /Marker_2_done/){m2=0}

     if(m1){a[i++]=$0}
     if(m2){b[j++]=$0}
  }
  FNR != NR {
     if ($0 ~ /Marker_1_start/){print;n1=1}
     if ($0 ~ /Marker_2_start/){print;n2=1}
     if ($0 ~ /Marker_1_done/){n1=0}
     if ($0 ~ /Marker_2_done/){n2=0}

     if(n1)
       for (k = 0; k < i; k++)
         print a[k]
     else if(n2)
       for (l = 0; l < j; l++)
         print b[l]
     else
       print
  }'  ./file_2 ./file_1
```

#### Output

```
$ ./filemerge.sh
text text text
text blabla
Marker_1_start
11
1111
Marker_1_done
any text
in between blabla
Marker_2_start
2222
22
Marker_2_done
text text
```

Comment: @Dennis he wasn't invited to the party